# Can't install SDK6 in Xcode5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have copy the sdk6.1 from xcode4 to the folder of xcode5, as shown below

[image]

but the xcode5 doesn't give the option for sdk6 in the base sdk

[image]

Also, when i try to build the project from xcodebuild, it will say that can't locate iphoneos6.1.

is there anyone have idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy the SDK, not the simulator files. That's why you do not see it. This is the correct path:

> Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

Note that you should copy the `iPhoneOS6.1.sdk` not `iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk`. So go to xcode 4 in that path I wrote above, take the correct folder and copy it to the same path in xcode 5.

Comment: Thanks, i took the folder by mistake. @Nikos M.